# Cookies included in request header, but express returns empty cookies (using Amazon Load Balancer)

Tags: express, http, cookies, fetch, amazon-elb

I'm doing `fetch` from my frontend to my express backend. But express logs `req.cookies` as `''` (empty). I'm using cookieParser.

Why is express not finding the cookie, even though the browser shows the cookies being sent?

Note: I'm using cookies forwarded by my load balancer, which does the authentication and sends the session over.

### Frontend

```js
    fetch(`${MY_URL}/logout`, {
      credentials: 'include',
    })
```

### NodeJS

```js
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/logout", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.headers) // see below
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.cookies))); // logs {}
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.signedCookies))); // logs {}

  // do stuff with cookie
});
```

Headers

```
{
  ...
  cookie: ''
}
```

Cookie in Headers is an empty string

Network tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working. Eventually the solution was that the Load balancer automatically forwards these headers to the backend silently. For my `/logout` api, instead of trying to grab the cookies from the headers, I set them regardless. Something like this:

```
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("AWSELBSessionCookie", "", {
    maxAge: -1,
    expires: Date.now(),
    path: '/'
  }

  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, no-store, max-age=0");
  res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  res.setHeader("Expires", -1);
  res.redirect("https://my-login-page.com");
})
```